# If statement displaying a NaN message instead of custom alert

Tags: javascript, alert

I have an if statement that checks to see if a number that the user enters is a number between 0 and the last index of an array. When I enter something other than a number, instead of going to the "else" portion of the code and displaying the alert message, it displays "NaN".

```
$("#delete_task").click(function() {   
        var taskIndex = prompt("Please enter the index number of the task to delete.",0);
        if(!isNaN(taskIndex) && taskIndex >= 0 && taskIndex < tasks.length) {
            tasks.sort();
            tasks.splice(taskIndex, 1);
            displayTaskList();
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a number between 0 and " + tasks.length-1 + ".");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `isNaN()` is not enough. You have to actively convert the value to a number before comparing it to other numbers; `prompt()` always returns a string.

Comment: So I would do ```var taskIndex = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the index number of the task to delete.",0))```?

Comment: I am not a fan of `parseInt()` because it allows strings like "123foo" without error. However otherwise it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt()` always returns a string.

Subtraction will attempt to coerce strings into numbers, so one way to correct this is by just ensuring that happens before the addition (concatenation) in the rest of the alert:

```js
let tasks = {length: "5"}

alert("Please enter a number between 0 and " + (tasks.length-1) + ".");
```

The parentheses here work exactly as in a math equation: they control the order of operations.  With the parentheses above, `tasks.length - 1` happens first, and because it's subtraction the variable (which we know contains only number characters because of the earlier `isNaN()` test) is successfully coerced into a number.  Then the "addition" operations happen (in left to right order) on the result, incidentally converting it back into a string.

Without the parentheses, the operation would go from left to right, so you'd first concatenate "Please enter a number between 0 and " and (the string) `tasks.length`.  Then it would attempt to subtract 1 from that, but because "Please enter a number" can't be converted into a number, you wind up with `NaN`. Finally the "." gets concatenated onto that, resulting in the string "NaN.":

```js
let tasks = {length: "5"}

alert("Please enter a number between 0 and " + tasks.length-1 + ".");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I had always thought that parenthesis were only necessary if there were multiple arguments. I thought that parenthesis were optional with simple arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Parentheses control the order of operations, just like in math equations.  I expanded the answer a bit to explain what's going on there in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to use the entered value as a number, while `prompt()` always returns a string, you need an extra step in there to convert the prompt response to a number:

```
$("#delete_task").click(function() {   
    var taskIndex = prompt("Please enter the index number of the task to delete.",0);
    taskIndex = Number(taskIndex); // or +taskIndex
    if(!isNaN(taskIndex) && taskIndex >= 0 && taskIndex < tasks.length) {
        tasks.sort();
        tasks.splice(taskIndex, 1);
        displayTaskList();
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a number between 0 and " + (tasks.length-1) + ".");
    }
});
```

The `isNaN()` check will still work, because if you type "foo" into the prompt dialog the conversion will result in `NaN`.  But after conversion to a number, the comparisons will work properly as *numeric* comparisons instead of string comparisons.

*edit* — another bug: in the error `alert()` call, you have to parenthesize `tasks.length-1`. If you don't, the expression in the call is interpreted as if it were written

```
(("Please enter a number between 0 and " + tasks.length) - 1) + "."
```

The subtraction operator always attempts to convert its arguments to numbers, and clearly the result of the initial *string* addition will end up being `NaN`. I've fixed the example code.

Comment: I added the line of code, but it still displays "NaN" instead of the alert I specified.

Comment: What exactly does `displayTaskList()` do?

Comment: Basically an array of "tasks" is displayed in a list, and the delete function (listed above) deletes that task from the list and from the array. displayTaskList() just re-displays the list in that array with the index specified removed from the array. It doesn't display any alerts.

Comment: I tested something and apparently "tasks.length-1" was the problem, I had to put it in parenthesis.

Comment: @coreynj yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have a String, you need convert taskIndex in Number with Number(taskIndex)